# Resizable header position

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Im setting a header that changes its appearance when the user scrolls down or when the window is minimized, the javascript works as it should but the header is getting in front of everything (because of its fixed position), is there any way I can keep it fixed but starting before the other elements? Here is the pictures:

Before scroll/resize:

[image]

After scroll/resize:

[image]

I wanted it to start before the section with the tickers (ibovespa, dolar, etc), like this:

[image]

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="header" id="navbar">
    <nav>
        <ul>
        <img class="logo" src="caf_logo.png"></img>
        <a href="/index.php">
        <li>
            <span class="navitemssp" id="navbar"><h1>Cafinvest</h1><h2>Home</h2></span>
        </li>
        </a>
        <a href="/empresas_listadas.php">
        <li>
            <span class="navitemssp" id="navbar"><h2>Empresas Listadas</h2></span>
        </li>
        </a>
        <a href="/cryptosniffer.php">
        <li>
            <span class="navitemssp" id="navbar"><h2>Farejador Cripto</h2></span>
        </li>
        </a>
        <a href="/b3sniffer.php">
        <li>
            <span class="navitemssp" id="navbar"><h2>Farejador B3</h2></span>
        </li>
        </a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="majorindexes">
    <table class="indexes">
    <?php
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        if($row["Variação"]>0)
        {
            $variação=number_format($row["Variação"],2,',','.');
            $linvar="<td class='positive'>".$row['Display']."<br>".$variação."%"."</td>";
        }
        else
        {
            $variação=number_format($row["Variação"],2,',','.');
            $linvar="<td class='negative'>".$row['Display']."<br>".$variação."%"."</td>";
        }
        echo $linvar;
    }
}
?>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
....
</body>
```

The javascript:

```
<script>
let header = document.querySelector(".header");
window.onscroll=function()
{
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop >280)
    {
        if(header.classList.contains("active"))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            header.classList.toggle("active");
        }
    }
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop == 0 && header.classList.contains("active") && window.innerWidth >= 512)
    {
        header.classList.toggle("active");
    }
}
if (window.innerWidth < 512)
{
    header.classList.toggle("active");
}
window.addEventListener("resize", function ()
{
    if(!header.classList.contains("active") && window.innerWidth < 512)
    {
        header.classList.toggle("active");
    }
    else if(header.classList.contains("active") && window.innerWidth >= 512 && document.documentElement.scrollTop == 0)
    {
        header.classList.toggle("active");
    }
    else
    {
    }
});
</script>
```

Header:

```
div.header
{
text-align: center;
padding: 2px 2px;
border-radius: 5px;
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #fff2cc, #c68c53);
z-index: 100;
margin-bottom: 10px;
letter-spacing: 2px;
}
div.header.active
{
left: 0;
right: 0;
opacity: 0.5;
border-radius: 10px;
position: fixed;
}
```

The first section after the header:

```
div.parent
{
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
outline-style: solid;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
background-color: black;
opacity: 0.7;
display: flex;
border-radius: 5pt;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: Z-Index would change the element on top, I wanted it to begin before, I edited the post with how I would like it to look like.

Comment: Sorry, still don't get it. I have no idea what you actually want now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive made a improvisation that works for now, its not exactly how I wanted but Ill leave this answer here, Ive created a "Fake" div that activates with the header, so it serves as a "placeholder":

HTML:

```
<div class="header" id="navbar">
    <nav>
        <ul>
        <img class="logo" src="caf_logo.png"></img>
        <a href="/index.php">
        <li>
            <span class="navitemssp" id="navbar"><h1>Cafinvest</h1><h2>Home</h2></span>
        </li>
        </a>
        <a href="/empresas_listadas.php">
        <li>
            <span class="navitemssp" id="navbar"><h2>Empresas Listadas</h2></span>
        </li>
        </a>
        <a href="/cryptosniffer.php">
        <li>
            <span class="navitemssp" id="navbar"><h2>Farejador Cripto</h2></span>
        </li>
        </a>
        <a href="/b3sniffer.php">
        <li>
            <span class="navitemssp" id="navbar"><h2>Farejador B3</h2></span>
        </li>
        </a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="fake">
</div>
...
```

CSS:

```
div.fake
{
visibility: hidden;
}
div.fake.active
{
visibility: visible;
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #fff2cc, #c68c53);
height: 110px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
let header = document.querySelector(".header");
let fake = document.querySelector(".fake");
window.onscroll=function()
{
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop >280)
    {
        if(header.classList.contains("active"))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            header.classList.toggle("active");
        }
        if(fake.classList.contains("active"))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            fake.classList.toggle("active");
        }
    }
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop == 0 && header.classList.contains("active") && window.innerWidth >= 512)
    {
        header.classList.toggle("active");
    }
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop == 0 && fake.classList.contains("active") && window.innerWidth >= 512)
    {
        fake.classList.toggle("active");
    }
}
if (window.innerWidth < 512)
{
    header.classList.toggle("active");
    fake.classList.toggle("active");
}
window.addEventListener("resize", function ()
{
    if(!header.classList.contains("active") && window.innerWidth < 512)
    {
        header.classList.toggle("active");
    }
    else if(header.classList.contains("active") && window.innerWidth >= 512 && document.documentElement.scrollTop == 0)
    {
        header.classList.toggle("active");
    }
    else
    {
    }
    if(!fake.classList.contains("active") && window.innerWidth < 512)
    {
        fake.classList.toggle("active");
    }
    else if(fake.classList.contains("active") && window.innerWidth >= 512 && document.documentElement.scrollTop == 0)
    {
        fake.classList.toggle("active");
    }
    else
    {
    }
});
</script>
```

Result:

[image]

Thanks for the answers anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Use position sticky instead of fixed

```
div.header.active
{
left: 0;
right: 0;
opacity: 0.5;
border-radius: 10px;
position: sticky;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But the problem with sticky is that it stops after the first element, it doesn't follow through the whole page.